# c#,Matrices y sentencias de control: ingresar los datos de las calificaciones de los estudiantes de un año en particular

Tags: c#, array, poo, bucle-for, condiciones

disculpen la molestia pero en realidad ya no se que mas hacer, quisiera que alguien lo corrija por favor. No me ejecuta. SharpDevelop se cierra y cuando logra mostrar el resultado da caracteres extraños. Ayuda por favor.

> Escriba un programa que permita ingresar los datos de las
> calificaciones de los estudiantes de un año en particular, estos datos
> serán almacenados en estructuras de la forma:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Donde la estructura Estudiante posee dos miembros: • nombre: Almacena
> el nombre del estudiante • notas: variable del tipo Notas que permite
> almacenar las calificaciones de los estudiantes por cada una de sus
> asignaturas. Los miembros de la estructura Notas son:
>
> - nro_asignaturas: cantidad de asignaturas del estudiante
> - asignaturas: nombres de cada una de las asignaturas
> - calificaciones: nota obtenida por cada asignatura

> Crear un arreglo del tipo Estudiante que permita
> almacenar 5 estudiantes con sus asignaturas y respectivas
> calificaciones.

**Esto es lo que llevo hecho**

```
namespace Ejercicio1
{
class Program
{
    public struct Notas
    {
        public int nro_asignatuas;
        public string[] asignaturas;
        public int[] calificaciones;
    }

    public struct Estudiante
    {
        public string nombre;

        public Notas notas;
    }
    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Estudiante[] registro = new Estudiante[5];
        //Estudiante[] registro;
        
        

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            //my = 8;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("+---------------------+--------------+");
            Console.WriteLine("|      --- Registrando Datos ---     |");
            Console.WriteLine("+---------------------+--------------+");

            Console.WriteLine("Registro No: {i + 1}");

            Console.Write("Nombre: ");

            registro[i].nombre = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Asignaturas Totales: ");

            registro[i].notas.nro_asignatuas = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            registro[i].notas.asignaturas = new string[registro[i].notas.nro_asignatuas];

            registro[i].notas.calificaciones = new int[registro[i].notas.nro_asignatuas];

            Console.WriteLine("+---------------------+--------------+");
            Console.WriteLine("|MATERIAS             |CALIFICACIONES|");
            Console.WriteLine("+---------------------+--------------+");

            for (int j = 0; j < registro[i].notas.nro_asignatuas; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("|{j + 1}:                   |              |");
                registro[i].notas.asignaturas[j] = Console.ReadLine();
                registro[i].notas.calificaciones[j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                
            }

            Console.WriteLine("+---------------------+--------------+");
            /*Console.WriteLine("Presiona una tecla para continuar...");
            Console.ReadKey();*/
        }
        
       // Console.Clear();
        
        Console.WriteLine("+---------------------+--------------+");
        Console.WriteLine("|      --- Mostrando Datos ---       |");
        Console.WriteLine("+---------------------+--------------+");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Registro No: {i + 1}");
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre: {registro[i].nombre}");
            Console.WriteLine("Asignaturas Totales: {registro[i].notas.nro_asignatuas}");

            Console.WriteLine("+---------------------+--------------+");
            Console.WriteLine("|MATERIAS             |CALIFICACIONES|");
            Console.WriteLine("+---------------------+--------------+");

            for (int j = 0; j < registro[i].notas.nro_asignatuas; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("|{j + 1}:                   |              |");
                Console.WriteLine("{registro[i].notas.asignaturas[j]}");
                Console.WriteLine("{registro[i].notas.calificaciones[j]}");
                
            }

            Console.WriteLine("|====================================|");
            Console.WriteLine("+====================================+");

            
        }
        
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Esto es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. Resolver tareas no forma parte de la mecánica del sitio. Sino fomentar el aprendizaje. Para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida puedes: Cargar el código (que ya lo has hecho), contar lo que has investigado y hacer todo lo más conciso posible sin perder información importante. Es aconsejable no incluir enunciados completos en la pregunta ya que suelen ser largos.

Comment: *SharpDevelop se cierra y cuando logra mostrar el resultado da caracteres extraños* no nos da mucha información. Si tienes obtienes un error, agrégalo a la pregunta. También nos ayudaría saber hasta que parte el programa funciona bien.

Comment: @Mateo, gracias!! ya lo expresare mejor!!!. Lamento no haberme explicado mejor, no pretendo que me realicen la tarea sino que me ´puedan orientar en mi error. Pero entiendo que pueda haber confusion.

Comment: En principio y en un primer vistazo no le veo mas problema que olvidaste el $ para la interpolacion de strings (por ejemplo deberia ser Console.WriteLine(**$**"Registro No: {i + 1}"); )y que el es mejor usar un TryParse para hacer un cast de una cadena desconocida a un tipo numerico.
Por lo demás funciona sin problemas ¿Que error EXACTAMENTE te da?